# zola ssg dark/light dynamic svg icons

Tags: javascript, svg

On [my Zola based site](https://ntn888.github.io/blog/) using [serene](https://github.com/isunjn/serene) theme, there are icons on the front page top right. They are supplied by the theme and change dynamically for dark/light modes.

I want to introduce a new icon (donate/heart shape) that has this dual colour functionality. According to the theme [docs](https://github.com/isunjn/serene/blob/latest/USAGE.md#icon) the icon set comes from https://remixicon.com/.

When I downloaded SVG files from there myself the icon was statically black colour.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: i have little knowledge in front end web development. that may be the reason the question was a bit vague.. sorry for the mistake.. anyway i managed to fix it. i've put my answer below. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just had to edit the svg file. It's just a text file.

Comment: So instead of answering, just delete the question. If you think it is worth keeping for others, update both question and answer with much more information and code